# How can I force subclasses to redefine a constant in Java?

Tags: java, oop

How can I have a generic abstract class, let's say Animal, and have it implement a constant (or a variable; it doesn't mind) which must be redefined by all subclasses?

Example:

```
abstract class Animal {
    private static int venerableAge;
}
```

And force `Dog` to be defined something like

```
class Dog extends Animal {
    private static int venerableAge = 10;
}
```

**I don't want** different subclasses to be able to **read nor write** each others' value. Just the one of themselves.

I.e., each class must have its own static "instance" of the variable. And no one will access the parent's.

Is that possible in Java?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trick is to do this with getter methods rather than directly with fields:

```
abstract class Animal {
   abstract int getVenerableAge();
}

class Dog extends Animal {
   private static int venerableAge = 10;

   public int getVenerableAge() {
      return venerableAge;
   }
}
```

EDIT:
How about letting the constructor do the contract binding:

```
abstract class Animal {
    public Animal(int venerableAge){
       //carry out sense checks here. i.e.:
       if (venerableAge < 0) { /* doSomething */ }
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
   private static int venerableAge;

   public Dog(int age) {
      super(age)
      venerableAge = age;
   }
}
```

Now Dog and Cat are both forced to be created with venerable ages, but (as implemented above) can't see each others value.

Comment: I like the answer, but the method is now public, and I want the value not to be read by anyone but the own class. (Yet I want to force it to be set). I edited my question a bit to avoid confussion.

Comment: You can make the method protected instead of public, so other classes won't be able to access it.

Comment: @ssice Can you provide further details as to why you are trying to do this?  I'm not sure what you are trying to do makes sense.

Comment: Neither do I. It's a theroetical question more than anything. Force a subclass to redefine something internal.

Comment: venerableAge for a Dog is known by Dog, and for Cat is known by Cat, but those species don't know each other's venerableAge, nor can ask the other for it.